# Spark: Perform SQL function on RDD subsets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to perform SQL function on RDD subsets, increasing in size. For this I have to take subsets from input RDD with `take` function:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
// set up environment
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[5]")
  .setAppName("Test")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val cntPairsRdd = cntsRdd.map(n => {                                                                  
  val sample = data0.take(n)                                                                      
  val dataRDD = sc.parallelize(sample)                                                           
  val df = dataRDD.toDF()                                                                      
  val result = df.select( ...)                                                                                                      
  val xCnt = result.count                                                                
  (n, xCnt)  
})   
}
```

`cntsRdd` is a set of increasing integers. Function `take` returns a `list` not `RDD`. So to make my SQL work I need first to convert my list to `RDD` and then to `dataframe`. Unfortunately inside `map` function Spark does not allow to create another `RDD`. In other words in Spark one can not create `RDD` inside another `RDD`. Because of the same reason Spark does not support `SparkContext` serilization. I get serilization exception when trying to `sc.parallelize(sample)`.

Please advise some workaround to perform SQL function on RDD subsets, as defined in this scenario.

Comment: where is your sc (SparkContext) object defined, you need to post more code so we can help ;)

Comment: I have `sc (SparkContext)` defined in `main`. Please, see my update code above.